# Autocomplete Component of React Not working for filter in selection list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I am using Autocomplete of material ui, to filter list of values, i have used onChange event of AutoComplete. To make impact of manually typed values, I have used onChange event of TextFiled resides under AutoComplete.

But it conflicts with onChnage event of Autocomplete and list doesn't get filtered. Can any one guide me, where I have done mistake ?

Code is as below:

```
<Autocomplete
  freeSolo
  options={this.state.dimension.map(p => p)}
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      margin="normal"
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      autoComplete="off"
      required
      onChange={this.handleDimensionChangeManual}
    />
  )}
  onChange={this.handleDimensionChange}
  value={this.state.dimemsionValue}
/>
```

Both functions are as follows:

```
handleDimensionChangeManual (event) {
  let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);

  if (event.target.value && newState.dimemsionValue != event.target.value) {
    newState.dimemsionValue = event.target.value;
    if (
      newState.dimension.includes(newState.dimemsionValue) === false &&
      newState.dimemsionValue.length > 0
    ) {
      newState.remark =
        "Size might be non-standard and may have effect on price";
    } else {
      newState.remark = "";
    }
    newState.disableSubmit = true;
    newState.itemid = "";
    newState.cmtExistingItemRemark = "";
    newState.orderCode = "";
    this.setState(newState);
  }
};

handleDimensionChange (event, values) {
  let newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);

  if (values && newState.dimemsionValue != values) {
    newState.dimemsionValue = values;
    if (
      newState.dimension.includes(newState.dimemsionValue) === false &&
      newState.dimemsionValue.length > 0
    ) {
      newState.remark =
        "Size might be non-standard and may have effect on price";
    } else {
      newState.remark = "";
    }
    newState.disableSubmit = true;
    newState.itemid = "";
    newState.cmtExistingItemRemark = "";
    newState.orderCode = "";
    this.setState(newState);
  }
};
```